# Generating Documentation for your Salesforce Instance

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, documentation

I have been searching the internet for documentation of an Salesforce instance for a long time. It's  always been a tiring job and takes a lot of time to document an instance. I'm aware of ApexDocs which takes care of the Apex classes like JavaDocs. I'm also aware of appexchange products like Octopus.

I'm looking more into a logic which would help me document other metadata components fields, workflow rules, validation rule etc. I would like to know what the salesforce community is already using or love to use.

I would be more than happy if there any suggestions or ideas. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MnZ Are you looking for admin tools, developer techniques, or both?

Comment: Any one of them would be great!

Comment: We created an app years ago called Drop My Dossier. It's not complete (as a lof of info wasn't available when we developed it) and basically unsupported at this point, but you can still get it and it can dump a bunch of information around custom fields etc. into a Word Doc.

Comment: @MattLacey That would be a nice to have application

Comment: Give it a whirl, free trial available on AppExchange, I can fix you up with a licence.